# NSwag customizing JSON output

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, nswag

I have a class:

```
class Test {
  public IPAddress Ip {get; set; }
}
```

By default, Nswag (`Nswag.AspNetCore` package) at http://localhost:1234/swagger serializes it as so, in the preview "Example" output:

```
[    
  "Ip": {
     "AddressFamily": 0,
     "ScopeId": 0,
     "IsIPv6Multicast": true,
     "IsIPv6LinkLocal": true,
     "IsIPv6SiteLocal": true,
     "IsIPv6Teredo": true,
     "IsIPv4MappedToIPv6": true,
     "Address": 0
    }
]
```

I want to custimize it, so that it serializes just the Ip field as a `string` without all the other type properties of `IPAddress`.

To do that, I created my own `JsonConverter`:

```
public class IPAddressConverter : JsonConverter
{ 
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(IPAddress));
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value,   JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(value.ToString());
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    { 
        return IPAddress.Parse((string)reader.Value);
    }
}
```

And verified that it works with JSON.Net.

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { Converters =  { new IPAddressConverter() } };
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(IPAddress.Parse("123.123.123.123"), settings);
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IPAddress>("123.123.123.123", settings);
```

Now I wanted to plug this into NSwag. I modified the NSwag settings like so inside ASP.Net's Startup.cs:

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseMvc();

        var swaggerSettings = new SwaggerUi3Settings()
        { 
            ContractResolver = new CustomSwaggerContractResolver(),
            DefaultPropertyNameHandling = NJsonSchema.PropertyNameHandling.Default /* If this is not set to default it raises an exception when a ContractResolver is set and then swagger page does not load at all */
        };

        app.UseSwaggerUi3(typeof(Startup).Assembly, swaggerSettings);
 }
```

#

```
public class CustomSwaggerContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{   
    protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType)
    {  
        JsonContract contract = base.CreateContract(objectType);

        if (objectType == typeof(IPAddress))
        {
            contract.Converter = new IPAddressConverter();
        }  

        return contract;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately when I browse to http://localhost:1234/swagger to see the Json "Example" output of my `Test` class, it is still including all the properties of `IPAddress` instead of `Ip` field being serialized as a simple `string`.

When I debug I can see that code inside `CustomSwaggerContractResolver` is called, and the converter is assigned, but the `IPAddressConverter` itself is never being called.

Is there anything that I am missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Because the transformation of a converter cannot be reflected (it is procedural) you need to add a type mapper

https://github.com/RSuter/NJsonSchema/wiki/Type-Mappers

and map the ipaddress type to a simple string schema

(NJsonSchema is the base of NSwag)

Comment: can you describe how the example value is generated?  Does it not pass a "new" object thru the serializer and does it instead use the schema to set the default values?  I certainly understand that the model would not pick up converter changes since nswag can't see them as part of the type, but I'm not sure why the example wouldn't change (even though it wouldn't match the model).